# Give Apache2 write permissions network share

Tags: permissions, shared-folders

I have just installed ownCloud. I chose the data directory (default: /var/www/cloud/data/) to be on a network share on my windows server.

This share is located at

```
/home/christophe/SeagateDrive/OwncloudData/
```

I mounted this share by adding this line to fstab:

```
//192.168.1.130/Seagate /home/christophe/SeagateDrive cifs user=administrator,password=pwd 0 0
```

But now I get an error from ownCloud saying that the user does not have write permissions to this directory so I did the following:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /home/christophe/SeagateDrive/OwncloudData
```

But this doesn't fix the problem. Everytime I navigate to the directory and do

```
ls -ld
```

the only user showing up is root.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by now.

The solution was to edit the fstab file.

In there I had to give the extra parameters:

```
gid=www-data
file_mode=0770
dir_mode=0770
```

This gave the group www-data write permissions.

Answer (score 0):

To give write permissions you should use the following command:

```
chmod 777 /home/christophe/SeagateDrive/OwncloudData/
```

or

```
chmod go+rwx /home/christophe/SeagateDrive/OwncloudData/
```

Changing the owner is not a good ideea in this case. You can be the ownner of a file, but you may not have read/write access to that file.

Comment: Shouldn't I specify that I want to give write access to www-data? This still gives me root only when I "ls -ld" and ownCloud still complains about not being able to write to the directory.

Comment: @ChristopheDeTroyer You don't have to do nothing else. See my new edits.

Comment: I understand your comment, but executing those two command (or any of the two) does not solve my problem. I tried each of both and restarted apache2 but apache2 still has no write access.

Comment: @ChristopheDeTroyer Sorry, I was thinking to a file. Is a directory in fact so you should use `chmod 777`. I edited my answer.